# django-autocompletion-light simple foreign key completion shows not editable drop-down widget

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I have a model for countries:

```
    class Country(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

That is referred by a foreign key in the UserDetails model:

```
    class UserDetails(models.Model):

        ...
        country = models.ForeignKey(Country,verbose_name='Country',null=True, blank=True, default = None)
```

By using django-autocomplete-light I would light that when inserting the country I have a text widget that completes while writing the first letters.

Thus, I have prepared:

```
    class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
        def get_queryset(self):

            qs = Country.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

With urls.py:

```
    app_name='shared'
    urlpatterns = [
        url(
            r'^country-autocomplete/$',
            CountryAutocomplete.as_view(),
            name='country-autocomplete',
        ),
    ]
```

And for the UserDetails form:

```
    class UserDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

        country = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Country.objects.all(),
            widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='shared:country-autocomplete')
            )

        class Meta:
            model = UserDetails
            fields = [...,"country"]
```

As a template I have used:

```
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ user_details_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'autocomplete_light/select2.css' %}" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/select2.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/forward.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

I have copied all the static files in a folder called 'static' in the root of the project, and I have set STATIC_URL='/static/' in the site settings.
While doing the get call, the runserver logging gives for the static files:

```
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /accounts/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2344
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/select2.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/select2.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/autocomplete_light/forward.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[23/Oct/2016 17:44:59] "GET /static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

When I send a get directly to the autocomplete view, I get as a result what I expect:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/shared/country-autocomplete/?q=u

{"pagination": {"more": false}, "results": [{"text": "USA", "id": 3}]}
```

However, if I go to the registration form, for the country field, I get such a widget:

[image: country_widget]

That is empty and cannot be edited.
How can I have a text widget that suggest country names while typing letters?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I imported a css as a javascript file, 
changing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css' %}"></script>
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css' %}" />
```

the autocompletion worked as wanted.