# django-autocomplete-light displays empty dropdown in the form

Tags: jquery, django, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to use django-autocomplete-light
From this tutorial
https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst

I Installed it with pip and added it to my settings file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
```

for my tenant value

My tenant  model is

```
class Tenant(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s ' % ("#", self.id,"first_name", self.first_name, "last_name")
```

In my autocomplete  view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from dal import autocomplete
from client.models import Tenant


    class TenantAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
        def get_queryset(self):
            # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
            if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                return Tenant.objects.none()

            qs = Tenant.objects.all()

            if self.q:
                qs = qs.filter(last_name__istartswith=self.q)

            return qs
```

in autocomplete  url

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include,patterns
from client import views 

    urlpatterns = [
        url(
            r'^tenant-autocomplete/$',
            views.TenantAutocomplete.as_view(),
            name='tenant-autocomplete',
        ), 
    ]
```

and in form

```
class LeaseTenantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tenant = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=LeaseTenant.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='tenant-autocomplete')
        )
    class Meta:
        model = LeaseTenant
        exclude = ['lease']
```

However after rendering in browser  I don't see the input text field but the empty  dropdown.
in  actual view

```
def tenant_new(request,pk,uri):
    lease = get_object_or_404(Lease, pk=pk)
    title = 'tenant'
    uri = _get_redirect_url(request, uri)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LeaseTenantForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tenant = form.save(commit=False)  
            tenant.lease = lease      
            tenant.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, str(tenant.id) + "-SUCCESS Object created sucssefully")


            return redirect(uri)
    else:
        form = LeaseTenantForm()
    return render(request, 'object_edit.html', {'form': form, 'title': title, 'extend': EXTEND})
```

My template file

```
{% block title %}
        Add/Edit {{ title  }}
{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <h4>{{ title  }}</h4>
                    <br><div class="center">
                <form method="POST"  class="form" action="" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form|crispy}}



                        {{ form.media }}

                        <BR><BR>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

 {% endblock content %}
```

So basically the autocomplete is not working .
What  should I validate to make it work?

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you forget `else` statement after `Tenant.objects.none()`

Comment: I'm getting this exact same error, I'll let you know if I figure it out

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was running into the same problem. This was a good reference: [django-autocompletion-light simple foreign key completion shows not editable drop-down widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206067/django-autocompletion-light-simple-foreign-key-completion-shows-not-editable-dro)

Make sure you are loading the jquery in your header file and that you use the `{{ form.media }}` tag for your form.

Here is how I load the jquery in my header file:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also, have you tried going to the `tenant-autocomplete/` url to see if you get the results on that page like it is mentioned in the tutorial https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html

If you can't get results from the url that should be the first bug you fix.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I get result from the url. 
Can you show me you view where you  call the final form  ?

Comment: I don't get it . The template in the question you referring to, is  actually template for autocomplete view only or this is the actual template for actual form.?

Comment: Well I define my form in my forms.py file, then I create in my view file. Then to refer to it in the template you just write '{{<name of form>.as_p }}'

Comment: Mysteriously it started to work . I assume something was wrong with my tag  {{ form.media }} in template . Thank you joe I really needed some support .

Comment: Upvoted, awesome response. Has the same problem and adding {{ form.media }} did the job. That was so so easy to overlook in the tutorial!