# adding a new record from django-autocomplete-light?

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to add new record from django-autocomplete-light.

below I describe how I set it up
[django-autocomplete-light displays empty dropdown in the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574039/django-autocomplete-light-displays-empty-dropdown-in-the-form/40578839?noredirect=1#comment68466720_40578839)

I am reading the docs and a bit confused (I usually use only function views and this is probably why).

Can someone please provide some example ?