# Why does django autocomplete dont work on first page visit

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

before python 2.7 code for autocomplete works fine, but after python3 autocomplete dont work as it is, everytime i visit the page the field is always blank and the select2 is not fount everytime I check in google chrome network

```
<link href="{% static 'autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{% static 'autocomplete_light/select2.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/select2.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

forms.py

```
        widgets = {
            'tags': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(url='tags_autocomplete'),

        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this [django-autocomplete-light displays empty dropdown in the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574039/django-autocomplete-light-displays-empty-dropdown-in-the-form) I just added `{{ form.media }}` on the header an it work